# Checking date from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to produce a function where I check the date is in the last fortnight.
This is something I have never done before.

I have produced a mysql_query

```
$q = "SELECT date_subbmited FROM ".TBL_CONF_RESULTS." WHERE home_user = '$u' OR away_user = '$u'";
```

That would select the date and in PHP i could check whether it was in the last fornight?

Or I could check within the SQL if the date was within the last fornight?

Whats the best practice here?
And how would I go about doing this?

date_submitted is the date i want to check, and $u is just the username.

Thanks

Comment: a fortnight is 2 weeks, right?

Comment: Yes it is, also can you add 6 hours onto a now() function?

Comment: Ah, changed 1 to 14 in my answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Example:

```
$q = "SELECT date_subbmited FROM ".TBL_CONF_RESULTS." WHERE (home_user = '$u' OR away_user = '$u') AND date_subbmited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after something like this:

```
SELECT date_submitted FROM table
WHERE date_submitted >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK )
```